# How to format a UK bank sort code?

Tags: php, format, bank

As part of a form I collect a users bank details which includes their sort code. The sort code is stored in the database as six numbers, for example `771731`.

I'd prefer to store the sort code in this format (without the hyphens) as it makes it easier for me to work with in other areas of the site. I want to output the sort code in one area of the site but in the format `77-17-31` using PHP.

I have searched Google for a solution but surprisingly found very little.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the prefect use-case for [`wordwrap()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php), just use it like this:

```
$code = "771731";
echo wordwrap($code, 2, "-", TRUE);
```

output:

```
77-17-31
```

Comment: Very elegant solution!

Answer (score 1):

Just figured this out using PHP functions, thought I'd post the answer in case it helped anyone else doing a Google search...

```
function formatSortCode($str) {
    return implode("-", str_split($str, 2));
}

echo formatSortCode('771731'); // outputs 77-17-31
```

Comment: You don't need to write your own function, PHP already has one

Answer (score 1):

I arrived here looking for a JavaScript answer not realising it was a PHP question. Tweaking @MichaelLB's answer, the **JavaScript** translation is

```
function formatSortCode(str) {
    return (String(str).match(/.{1,2}/g) || []).join('-');
}

formatSortCode(123456789);

>>> "12-34-56-78-9"
```

Comment: I arrived here too and decided to create a post with the Javascript question on.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75447296/how-do-i-format-an-account-name-and-or-sort-code-using-javascript